# Encoding.com transcoding speed

Tags: json, performance, encoding, ffmpeg

`ffmpeg` presets are:

`ultrafast`, `superfast`, `veryfast`, `faster`, `fast`, `medium`, `slow`, `slower`, `veryslow` and `placebo`

How should my json request look like if i want as encoding speed `slow`?

My json so far:

```
{
    "query": {
        "userid": "79943",
        "userkey": "XXX",
        "action": "addMedia",
        "notify": "aw3somevideo@gmail.com",
        "format": [{
            "output": "mpeg_dash",
            "sizes": "426x240,640x360",
            "bitrates": "400k,800k"
        }, {
            "output": "ipad_stream",
            "sizes": "426x240,640x360",
            "bitrates": "400k,800k"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you sending this json data to?

Comment: @rogerdpack to the encoding api from encoding.com: http://manage.encoding.com

Comment: see if they have an option for libx264 parameters, GL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and the help with @rogerdpack and the `encoding.com`support i found an answer

It can be set in the video codec parameters:

```
Slow:
--me umh --subme 8 --ref 5 --b-adapt 2 --direct auto
```

The JSON structure will look like this:

```
"video_codec_parameters": {
"coder": "1",
"flags": "+loop",
"flags2": "+bpyramid+wpred+mixed_refs+dct8x8-fastpskip",
"cmp": "+chroma",
"partitions": "+parti8x8+parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8",
"me_method": "umh",
"subq": "7",
"me_range": "16",
"bf": "16",
"keyint_min": "25",
"sc_threshold": "40",
"i_qfactor": "0.71",
"b_strategy": "1",
"qcomp": "0.6",
"qmin": "10",
"qmax": "51",
"qdiff": "4",
"directpred": "1",
"level": "30",
"refs": "4",
"psy": "0"
},
```

Comment: Weird. The whole point of the preset option is to avoid setting all these individual options.

Comment: I know but that's what the support wrote to me [http://i.imgur.com/ijecXyj.png](http://i.imgur.com/ijecXyj.png)

Comment: How inefficient. Also, does not appear to be options used for a typical "slow" preset. They should fire this "Zach" charlatan. Did you try removing the billion options and use `"preset": "slow"` instead?

Comment: I tried `"preset": "slow"` but didn't seem to have any effect